# select the Div without specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-selectors

Q:

I have the following case :

Div contains a link , i wanna to just select the div without the link,i mean ,when clicking on the div i wanna specific action differs from clicking the link.through some JQuery.

the structure i work on is:(by firebug)

`<div class ="rsAptContent">
sql
<a class = "rsAptDelete" href = "#" style ="visibility: hidden;">Delete</a>
</div>`

the JQuery code:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


    $(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
            ShowDialog(true);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    function ShowDialog(modal) {
        $("#overlay").show();
        $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

        if (modal) {
            $("#overlay").unbind("click");
        }
        else {
            $("#overlay").click(function(e) {
                HideDialog();
            });
        }
    }

    function HideDialog() {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
    } 

</script>`
```

when i click on the link ,i don't want to execute the Jquery code , how to select the div without the link in.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).hasClass('rsAptDelete')) return false;
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If the target is the link the event is cancelled;

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like the stopPropagation() code?

```
$(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            ShowDialog(true);
            return false;
        });

    });
```

That should stop the link from executing.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Edit:  Distinguish between clicking the link and clicking on any part of the content except the link

```
    $(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
                var $target = $(e.target);
                if($target.is(a){
                  // It's the link.
                }else{
                  // else it's not
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: no i don't want to stop the link event, i want to distinguish between clicking the link and clicking on any part of the content except the link , how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the clicked target element than perform action

to get info about which element is click use below script

```
function whichElement(event){
    var tname
    tname=event.srcElement.tagName
    alert("You clicked on a " + tname + " element.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a click handler on the delete link, then just stop the event propagation there by using `stopPropagation()`.

```
$(".rsAptDelete").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```